# What is the interpretation of "p[z] <-- y" pseudocode in java?

Tags: java, pseudocode, red-black-tree, interpretation

This is for a red black tree.

For the pseudocode "p[z] <-- y", would the interpretation in java be:

```
z.getParent() = y;
```

or

```
z.setParent(y);
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct code would be `z.setParent(y);`

Be aware that `z.getParent() = y;` is invalid code. The assignment operator `=` stores the result of evaluating the expression to the right of the `=` into a variable, attribute or array position to the left of the `=`. In an expression like the first one in your question, you'd be trying to assign the value `y` into the result of calling `z.getParent()` - that is, trying to assign a value into another value, and that won't work.

The right way to change an attribute is by calling the corresponding `setXXX()` method, or by directly assigning to the attribute if it was declared non-private, like this: `z.parent = y;`